# Stop Thunderbird from automatically hyperlinking on send

Tags: thunderbird, hyperlink, autocorrect

Uppity Thunderbird has decided it's smarter than me. When sending a message, it automatically converts anything that looks like a URL to a hyperlink, even if I made sure it was not a hyperlink in the editor.

Besides being annoying, the automatic link insertion causes Thunderbird to send the message as HTML when it would otherwise be sent as plain text.

How can I show it who's boss?

Comment: I've not got Thunderbird installed on this machine, but doesn't setting the e-mail format to plain text work?

Comment: The plain text email I sent looked like it had links when I looked at it in the Sent folder, but that was actually Thunderbird "linkifying" the plain text when I was viewing it. The source (ctrl-U) showed no links. I wish I could control the display too (and tell the recipient program to not mess with the email content).

Answer (score 2):

**From [mozillaZine (Mozilla Wiki)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_generated_automatically):**

*Suppressing automatically-generated links*

> It is possible to take some steps to suppress automatically-generated links, but you cannot completely suppress them.

*Sending messages*

> When you write an HTML message, you can suppress automatically-generated links.
>    Select the text that Thunderbird normally linkifies.
>    Choose Insert – HTML... In the HTML editor, type anchor tags around the text.
>    For example, if you type this but you do not want Thunderbird to linkify it:
>    `someone@example.org`
>    In the HTML editor, change it to:
>    `<a>someone@example.org</a>`
>    If there is already an anchor tag with attributes (class and href, typically), 
>    then remove the attributes to leave the tag looking like the example above.
>    Note:  People who receive your message might still see a link, 
>    if they use mail clients that linkify when they display messages.
>    For example, Thunderbird users will probably see a link if they choose:
>    **View – Message Body As – Plain Text**

---

If your message is sent using HTML formatting, Mozilla Thunderbird will automatically hyperlink URLs and email addresses.

**In the [plain text version](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_%28Thunderbird%29), the URLs and email addresses will remain untouched, however the recipient's email program will typically turn these addresses into hyperlinks.**

If you wish to send the mail in plain text mode, [here is a quick tutorial](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/16/switch-between-html-and-plain-text-emails-in-thunderbird/) on how to switch between HTML and plain text emails in Thunderbird (notice the difference between HTML and plain text modes for reading (viewing received messages) and sending (composing new messages and sending them)).